# PHP split string twice

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with a transaction field, this displays products brought on my website. I am trying to develop an admin interface where i  can see the products brought.

The string looks like this
`37,2:27,1:5,3:94,10:49,15:`

This basically means that the customer ordered product ID number 37 with the quantity of 2. Included in their transacvtion was product id 27 with qty 1 and so on.

`product_id,ordered_quantity:nextproduct_id,next_orderedquantity`.

In order to display this information I need to break this down. I have tried php explode but having some trouble. So we need to split the product on colon `:` and the qty and id by `comma`. The string can be one product or many.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: You're basically inventing a way of storing something that could have been a table in a single field. Just use a regular table instead with user_id, product_id and ordered_quantity as columns. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You are correct, I could have done. But then i would have further complications should the customer have two different transactions on my site, I would have to find the latest one. So both ways work fine except this one is with 1 less table

Comment: Associate an order_id and that problem will be solved as well. You make it sound like having few tables is a quality in itself which is absolutely not the case - just consider data normalization. Besides, if you want users to have multiple transactions (as you mention yourself) on your site, you'll probably need an extra table as well. If not, I dare not even ask about what design you're considering.

Comment: Additionally, modifying the shopping cart, adding or removing items requires you to first retrieve the entire string and do a lot of slow string manipulation on it. Count items is a rather tedious task as well. These would tasks would all be a lot simpler using a proper design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ids = '37,2:27,1:5,3:94,10:49,15';
$products = explode(':', $ids);
$productAndQuantity = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $exploded = explode(',', $product);
    $productAndQuantity[$exploded[0]] = $exploded[1];
}
```

You get a profuct id - quantity array.

This way of storing data is non-scalable and error-prone. Why not use a table with the following fields: userId, productId, quantity?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. I have it printing out nicely in a table with the other information now :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is something I threw together -

```
$str = '37,2:27,1:5,3:94,10:49,15:';

$a = explode(':',$str); // split by colon ":"

$data = array(); 
foreach ($a as $product) {  // iterate over each product
    $item = explode(',',$product); // split product and quanitity
    $data[$item[0]] = array(  // use product_id [0] as array key
      'product_id'=>$item[0],
      'quantity'=>$item[1]
    );
}

// in this example there is a trailing colon - this removes it.    
array_pop($data);

print_r($data);
```

---

```
Array
(
    [37] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 37
            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 27
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [quantity] => 3
        )
    ...
)
```